# android notification not working for vivo funtouchOS

Tags: android

one of my user has vivo mobile with funtouchOS with latest version of PD1613F_EX_A_1.12.1 she is not getting the notification messages where else for other users they are getting notifications.
And also she says, she is getting the notification for messenger, WhatsApp and other app just not for my app.

So let me know if someone has same kind of issue or someone can help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: you might need to add your app to `autostart` list like xiaomi miui

Comment: thank for you help, my issue is solved some error in backend side FCM error

Comment: can you please explain what kind of error you got?

Comment: i am also facing same issue